Printing a negative _BitInt in C23
If I have the following code:
_BitInt(6) c = -20;
printf("_BitInt(6) -> c: %d\n", c); 

The printf gives as value 236 and not -20
I noticed that to print the correct value I should write the following code instead using the cast to int operator.
printf("_BitInt(6) -> c: %d\n", (int)c);

What is the explanation?
Maybe printf without (int)c makes a wrong conversion of c into an unsigned 8 bit int?

This is why you should compile with warnings. Clang diagnoses this by default but it seems gcc does not for some reason.

Bit-precise types using _BitInt are exempt from the regular integer promotion rules, which dictate that any integer type whose rank is smaller than int is promoted to int when used in most expressions.
This is spelled out in section 6.3.1.1p2 of the C23 standard:

The value from a bit-field of a bit-precise integer type is converted
to the corresponding bit-precise type. If the original type is not a
bit-precise integer type (6.2.5) and if an int can represent all
values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is
converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions.
All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

This subsequently means that you're passing an argument to printf whose type doesn't match the given format specifier, and doing so triggers undefined behavior.
There was a new width modifier wN (where N is an integer) added that allows passing a bit-precise type.  So the correct format specifier would be %w6d.  However not all compilers support it yet, in particular gcc doesn't have it as of version 14.2 according to godbolt.

Yes, this is interesting however as I said it seems like under the hood _BitInt(6) has been converted as unsigned int. In fact into a 2 complement representation for -20 we have this 6 bit value: 101 100. After that if printf "convert" into an 8 bit unsigned int we have 1110 1100 with 236 as decimal value. So it doesn' seem an  undefined behavior.

@xdevel2000 Undefined behavior means the standard doesn't require that any particular thing happens.  If you compile on a different machine or with different options you may get different results.

I can understand. Just as a side note: if I declare this:  _BitInt(10) a = 100; and then I write printf("a: %d\n", a); the compiler warns me but the a value is printed correctly. So even if there is an undefinied behavior the printf beahvior is right.  Did it happen by chance?

@xdevel2000 Yes, one way undefined behavior can manifest itself is that things appear to work properly.  Then later you make an unrelated change to your code and now you get a different result.

Exempting bit-precise integers from the integer promotion rules seems inconsistent and confusing: _BitInt(6) c = -20; int d = c * c; printf("d=%d\n", d); will output 16, not 400.  This is so confusing and no warning is issued.  I understand the behavior is actually undefined because of signed arithmetic overflow, but the same confusion occurs for unsigned _BitInt(6) c = 20; unsigned d = c * c; printf("d=%u\n", d);

Do you have any reference for the width modifier wN for _BitInts? Can't seem to find it

Bit-precise integers are not subject to the integer promotions. That means they don't get automatically converted in any way when you pass them to variadic functions, like printf.
printf is receiving the argument as a _BitInt(6). Under the hood, that probably looks like a char, but in terms of language semantics, it's a _BitInt(6). The %d format specifier requires an int, not a _BitInt(6). Thus, your program has undefined behavior.

Check my answer to @dbush and tell me what you think about...
